# How do I create a subfolder with a specific name? (the date of data extraction)

Tags: python, selenium

I've created a variable "dt" which is the date of today.
**Now I want to create** a subfolder which name should be (Partial Update + str(dt)

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now() 
subfolder_name = ("Partial Update - " + str(dt))

os.makedirs(os.path.join("H:\......\VICTOR KURC\",subfolder_name))
```

### My problem is that the subfolder is not being created with the name that is need, only with a standard name (using stantard lines of code).

How do I fix it?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: what does `str(dt)` give you? Have you tried manually creating a folder with that name? Also, I would be surprised if that ran at all since you're escaping your last `"`.

Comment: @Axe319 yes, but I'm improving a script for a webscrapping application, so I want the it to be as simple as possible for the user.

Comment: @VictorKurc my point is that the output of `str(dt)` is not a valid file/folder name in Windows. You would need to format the output to exclude special characters.

Comment: @Axe319 exactly, I didn't know that, but I just saw at Julios's answer down here how to exclude these characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
from datetime import datetime 

# place yourself in the same directory of the script you're running
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# format date without special characters
dt = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
subfolder_name = f"Partial Update - {dt}"

# if folder doesn't exist, create it
if not os.path.isdir(subfolder_name):
    os.mkdir(subfolder_name)
```

Comment: It worked, created the subfolder using:  

`# format date without special characters  
dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")  
subfolder_name = f"Partial Update - {dt}"  

# place yourself in the same directory of the script you're running  
os.chdir(os.path.dirname("H:\...\VICTOR KURC"))  

os.makedirs(os.path.join("H:\...\VICTOR KURC",subfolder_name))`